# Passing through an association attributes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `user` that has one `traversal`. The Traversal model has an attribute, frame. I can access it using

```
user.traversal.frame
```

but I seem to recall there is a ruby on rails means for making the following work.

```
user.traversal_frame
```

without an extra method in the User model i.e. without doing

```
def traversal_frame
  self.traversal.frame
end
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`delegate`](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method. Something like following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :traversal
  delegate :frame, to: :traversal
end
```

You can then use it like following

```
user.frame # => Same as user.traversal.frame
```

Note:- when `user` has no `traversal` then `user.frame` will throw an error `raises NoMethodError: undefined method 'frame'` to fixed this use following

```
delegate :frame, to: :traversal, allow_nil: true
```

To access it using `user.traversal_frame` you have to use `prefix` option as below

```
delegate :frame, to: :traversal, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: And if you want `user.traversal_frame`, add to User model: `delegate :frame, to: :traversal, prefix: true, allow_nil: true`.

Comment: Thanks @JagdeepSingh, i didn't knew it, I'll update the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for, but could not remember it.